# How to connect across multiple consecutive missing data values using geom_line?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, na

I have a similar problem to Q: Connecting across missing values with geom_line, but found the answers provided only connect the lines when there is one missing value only. If there are 2+ consecutive missing values the solutions offered do not apply.

I need to connect multiple observations made over time for individual trees. Sometimes measurements were missed such that there are missing values in my df, and sometimes an individual tree was missed more than one year in a row, such that there are multiple consecutive NAs.

When there is only one consecutive NA, using geom_line with this specification works a treat to connect across missing values:

```
geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$y),])
```

When there is more than one consecutive NA (i.e. 2 measurements missed) geom_line will not draw across the missing data. Applying !is.na to the whole df does not solve the problem, nor does using geom_path.

Here is code to generate a df that replicates the issue:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
tr1 <- c(20,25,18,16,22,12,NA,15,45)
tr2 <- c(12,NA,NA,NA,30,48,30,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(x, tr1,tr2)
```

The following code can be used to graph a) tree1 with NA missing, b) tree1 with NA bridged, b) tree2 with geom_line correction in code but missing the expected line across NAs

```
tree1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, tr1)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line()
tree1.fix <- ggplot(df, aes(x, tr1)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$tr1),])
nofix <- ggplot(df, aes(x, tr2)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = df[!is.na(df$tr2),])
grid.arrange(tree1, tree1.fix, nofix, ncol = 3)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_line()` does not connect across any missing data (NA). And `geom_point()` does not plot missing data either. That is the correct default behaviour for missing data. NA cannot be placed on numerical axes.

What you are doing with `df[!is.na(df$tr2),]` is **removing** the missing data before sending it to `geom_line()`, tricking into thinking that your data is complete.
To better understand this, print out `df[!is.na(df$tr2), c("x", "tr2")]`. That's the data that `geom_line()` receives. All of this data is displayed and connected. There are no NAs in that data, because you removed them.

In your "nofix example, you get a line from x=1 to x=5, over three consecutive NA.
So I assume that you mean that `geom_line()` does not continue after x=7?
But look at the data. There is no data after x=7. Every x>7 has y=NA. And if you remove NAs, then there is no data at all after x=7.

If your example had one more point, say x=10 y=10, then the line would continue from x=7 to x=10.

Comment: Thanks for running it to check cymon. You're right – the 'no fix' example is working on this abridged example... no idea why the same code wasn't doing it for me last night. Interestingly though, when I run this code on my big dataset (i.e. plot about 1000 trees at once) it doesn't seem able to compute all the line connections across removed NAs, but when subsetting down to 10-50 trees at a time the plots come out fine.

Comment: Like I already said, `geom_line()` never connects across NA. If missing data is present, it will interrupt the line at that position. What you are doing in your "fix" is to remove the rows with the missing data so `geom_line()` never knows they exist. 
So if in your big plot you are getting interrupted lines, that means your dataframe still contains missing data. Filter your df outside of the ggplot and run some diagnostics on the filtered df. Look for `NA`s, `NULL`s, `NaN`s, `Inf`s...

Comment: You may also want to look into the `complete.cases(df)` function instead of manually filtering for all the different types of non-values.

Comment: Yeh, understood and ran a bunch of checks. All the !complete.cases were NAs, and I was filtering them out within geom_line appropriately with the code we've discussed above. The issue (!!) was that I'd applied a ylim that cut off some points. Instead of drawing line that go out of the graphed space geom_line just won't draw lines for those points beyond the limits of the axes. Cheers for helping me rule some things out Simon